# How can I retrieve the statistics for any name or object by using sparql and dbpedia?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I want to retrieve the following statistics for any given **thing**:

- *dbpedia-owl:wikiPageInLinkCountCleaned*
- *dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRank*
- *dbpedia-owl:wikiHITS*
- *dbpedia-owl:wikiPageOutLinkCountCleaned*

---

**Method:**

What I am doing is very complicated.

- **First:** I am selecting all the properties by using the following query:

> select ?p ?o where {dbpedia:"+name+" ?p ?o }

- **Second:** Results will be saved in a dictionary. Finally I'll just search for the names `wikiPageInLinkCountCleaned`, `wikiPageRank`, `wikiHITS`, `wikiPageOutLinkCountCleaned` and then retrieve their values

---

I really can't find out how these properties fit in the triples of the dbpedia database. Do they?

Comment: I don't see *any* use of the properties in DBpedia right now.  can you provide an example of a resource that has values for them?

Comment: but also see [SPARQL query returning incomplete/inconsistent results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28435939/1281433) which mentions these properties.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dineshreddykdp/DBpedia_HITS_Scores

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I thank you for the dataset dbpedia_hits_scores even if it's late. I wanted to ask you is there a similiar dataset in the same turtle format that contains all the properties such as: **sameAs**, **wikipageredirects** etc..